# Joining Pandas tables and keep NaN values if dates is null

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let say I have multiple stock prices data with different dates. There are 100 dates in total, across all stocks. If I have 10 stocks, each with dates < 100, I would like to obtain a final dataframe in which, each stock has 100 dates, in total, the dataframe has 10*100 rows = 1000 rows, the date in which the stock does not have, it should be a row with NaN.

```
df1
        date ticker      open      high       low     close  volume
0 2007-01-03   0001  0.133293  0.133293  0.133293  0.133293    40.0
1 2007-01-04   0001  0.133293  0.133293  0.133293  0.133293     0.0
2 2007-01-05   0001  0.133293  0.133293  0.128697  0.133293   215.0

df2
        date ticker      open      high       low     close  volume
0 2007-01-01   0002  0.111111  0.111111  0.111111  0.111111    11.1
1 2007-01-02   0002  0.111111  0.111111  0.111111  0.111111    11.1
2 2007-01-04   0002  0.111111  0.111111  0.111111  0.111111    11.1
```

resulting in df

```
df1
        date ticker      open      high       low     close  volume
0 2007-01-01   0001       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN     NaN  
1 2007-01-02   0001       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN     NaN 
2 2007-01-03   0001  0.133293  0.133293  0.133293  0.133293    40.0
3 2007-01-04   0001  0.133293  0.133293  0.133293  0.133293     0.0
4 2007-01-05   0001  0.133293  0.133293  0.128697  0.133293   215.0
5 2007-01-01   0002  0.111111  0.111111  0.111111  0.111111    11.1
6 2007-01-02   0002  0.111111  0.111111  0.111111  0.111111    11.1
7 2007-01-03   0002       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN     NaN
8 2007-01-04   0002  0.111111  0.111111  0.111111  0.111111    11.1
9 2007-01-05   0002       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Set `date` as index and use `reindex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you first `concat` your dataframes, then `set_index` date and ticker, `reindex` with a `MultiIndex.from_product` with `unique` value from both columns and `reset_index`

```
df_f = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=0)
df_f = df_f.set_index(['date','ticker'])\
           .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df_f['date'].unique(), df_f['ticker'].unique()], 
                                                names=['date','ticker']))\
           .reset_index()#.sort_values(['ticker', 'date'])

print (df_f)
         date  ticker      open      high       low     close  volume
0  2007-01-03       1  0.133293  0.133293  0.133293  0.133293    40.0
1  2007-01-03       2       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN     NaN
2  2007-01-04       1  0.133293  0.133293  0.133293  0.133293     0.0
3  2007-01-04       2  0.111111  0.111111  0.111111  0.111111    11.1
4  2007-01-05       1  0.133293  0.133293  0.128697  0.133293   215.0
5  2007-01-05       2       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN     NaN
6  2007-01-01       1       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN     NaN
7  2007-01-01       2  0.111111  0.111111  0.111111  0.111111    11.1
8  2007-01-02       1       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN     NaN
9  2007-01-02       2  0.111111  0.111111  0.111111  0.111111    11.1
```

you can `sort_values` after depending on how you want the result sorted

Comment: Hi @Ben.T, the solution is working, imagine df_f is doing concat on more than 1000 tickers, each more than 10 years worth of data. Then the `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` is giving a huge performance issue. Any way to make it quicker?

Comment: @Irh09 you could try with `itertools.product` but I doubt it would make it so much quicker. or the solution of Erfan, but with `date_range=df['date'].unique()` instead of using the method `pd.date_range`

Comment: or another solution could be to get all the date possible before, reindex your original dfs and then concat

Answer (score 1):

First we concat the dataframes and check wat the lowest and highest date is, we use these dates to reindex our dataframes:

```
dfs = [df1, df2]

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
date_range = pd.date_range(df['date'].min(), df['date'].max(), freq='D')

df = (
    df.set_index('date')
    .groupby('ticker').apply(lambda x: x.reindex(date_range))
    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={'index':'date'})
)

        date  ticker      open      high       low     close  volume
0 2007-01-01     NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN     NaN
1 2007-01-02     NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN     NaN
2 2007-01-03     1.0  0.133293  0.133293  0.133293  0.133293    40.0
3 2007-01-04     1.0  0.133293  0.133293  0.133293  0.133293     0.0
4 2007-01-05     1.0  0.133293  0.133293  0.128697  0.133293   215.0
5 2007-01-01     2.0  0.111111  0.111111  0.111111  0.111111    11.1
6 2007-01-02     2.0  0.111111  0.111111  0.111111  0.111111    11.1
7 2007-01-03     NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN     NaN
8 2007-01-04     2.0  0.111111  0.111111  0.111111  0.111111    11.1
9 2007-01-05     NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN     NaN
```

Comment: You cannot be using `date_range = pd.date_range(df['date'].min(), df['date'].max(), freq='D')`, because not all days are trading days. For example 1st of Jan is not a trading day